# Google Data Studio - Comparison by previous month

Tags: google-data-studio

I have this simple data:

```
Date    Total Revenue
1/1/2017    $22,219.00
2/1/2017    $22,119.00
3/1/2017    $22,360.00
4/1/2017    $22,097.00
5/1/2017    $22,320.00
6/1/2017    $22,126.00
7/1/2017    $22,268.00
8/1/2017    $22,029.00
9/1/2017    $22,224.00
10/1/2017   $21,997.00
11/1/2017   $22,186.00
12/1/2017   $22,022.00
```

I am adding a table for this data in data studio. Now I want to do a comparison of each month with the previous one. But I get empty column when I set `Date Compare Period` to `Previous Period`.

This is how my table looks like in data-studio.

[image]