# Google data studio not showing comparison

Tags: google-data-studio

I have 2 data sources - one is Google Analytics, the other one is a table from big query:

[image]

I am simply trying to display the % change per day in both metrics, so for example in the first I would show:

```
(8239 - 1706) / 8239 * 100
(7802 - 8239) / 7802 * 100
# and so on, just daily percentage change
```

The same in the second table with `views`.

Before I used to use it like so:
[image]

And it would show me what I desire, but now all `%` changes are `-` and I can't understand why.

Maybe this can be resolved in using some custom `SQL`?

Comment: Related to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114338. I'm looking for the same answer. It's unfortunate that this is still an issue.